# How can I get load address of an iOS app?

Tags: ios

I would like to offer the option in my app to send stack trace of catched NSException by email. However, addresses are relocated so I would need the loaded base address for the trace to be meaningful.
  Is there a way to get this? The closest I did get is taking the pointer of a known function, which is something (I can calculate base address from it, after all), but is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: Why not just use Crashlytics?  You are re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I might, good tip, but nevertheless I am still interested in this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I have done in the past is log the mach header addresses within the log file, that the (server-based) symbolication tool can then use. The log file contained both log messages and the crash log.

```
// Dump the load addresses of AppName and libXxx.dylib to help tools/process_bug_reports.py
uint32_t numImages = _dyld_image_count();
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
    const struct mach_header *header = _dyld_get_image_header(i);
    const char *name = _dyld_get_image_name(i);
    const char *p = strrchr(name, '/');
    if (p && (strcmp(p + 1, "AppName") == 0 || strcmp(p + 1, "libXxx.dylib") == 0)) {
        loginf(@"module=%s, address=%p", p + 1, header);
    }
}
```